# C# Bond: Can I have List of custom class in my bond struct?

Tags: c#, database, database-design, object-storage, bond

I know lists are supported in Bond, I'm just wondering if we can create class like

```
class Car
{
    string Model;
    string PlateNumber;

    // ...
}
```

Can I then have something like this in the bond file?

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    struct Gallery
    {
        0: required List<Cars> AllCars;
    }
}
```

If it's possible, can anyone please write an example of how the complete bond file should be like?

Also where I should add the class definition to be able to use it like that?

Edit: I need the Car to be a bond struct to be serialized as part of Gallery, so whenever I retrieve Gallery object, I should be able to access and modify the list of cars belongs to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want Car to be a Bond struct, you can define it in the same .bond file as Gallery and then use it when defining the `AllCars` field. Here's an example gallery.bond:

```
namespace MyNameSpace;

struct Car
{
    0: string Model;
    1: string PlateNumber;
}

struct Gallery
{
    // Car needs to be defined/imported before Gallery so it's visible here
    0: required vector<Car> AllCars;
}
```

Note that Bond's `vector` field type maps to C#'s [`List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). (Bond's `list` maps to [`LinkedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx).)

The documentation for the `gbc` code generation tool talks, albeit briefly, about [the types a field definition](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/compiler.html#struct-definition) can have. If you end up needing recursive structs, you'll need to make use of [forward declarations](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/compiler.html#forward-declaration) and [nullable fields](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html#nullable-types).

If you wanted, you could put `Car` is its own .bond file and then import that .bond file into the one with `Gallery`. There's [an example showing how importing works](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cs/core/import), if you're interested.